# How do you request user input using Rx?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am writing a class that encapsulates a state machine that represents my applications attempts to communicate with my own web service. Basic states are disconnected, connecting, connected, and requiring credentials. I thought for good learning experience about using Rx to publish state changes with a BehaviorSubject (hopefully this in itself is good usage?). One of my states for this subject is the 'Requiring Credentials' where I need to prompt the user to provide a username and password before continuing. For the purposes of this exercise let us assume that the class is hosted in a Windows Console Application and that I want to prompt the user with

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
var userName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter password");
var password = Console.ReadLine();
```

As a result of my Rx BehaviorSubject hitting the state 'RequiresCredentials' and it should hit this every time this state is hit.

I have exposed the BehaviorSubject as itself (i.e. haven't hidden it behind an Observable interface or anything)

```
public BehaviorSubject<ConnectionState> State { get; }
```

and want this request for credentials to be blocking.

What process should I use for subscribing to this subject correctly, waiting for this input and finally returning control back to the calling thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using tasks or await, or anything asynchronous, Rx subscription code will observe on the same thread, and block if you're using blocking code. If you don't care about the input, then you can do a straight `Subscribe`. If you want to use the inputted username/password, then you can use `Select`. So this would work:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var subject = new BehaviorSubject<ConnectionState>(ConnectionState.Disconnected);

        var getCredentials = subject.Where(cs => cs == ConnectionState.RequiresCredentials)
            .Select(cs =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
                var userName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter password");
                var password = Console.ReadLine();
                return Tuple.Create(userName, password);
            });
        using (var subscription = getCredentials.Subscribe())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Changing to Connecting...");
            subject.OnNext(ConnectionState.Connecting);
            Console.WriteLine("Changing to RequiresCredentials...");
            subject.OnNext(ConnectionState.RequiresCredentials);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected.");
            subject.OnNext(ConnectionState.Connected);
        }

    }
}

enum ConnectionState
{
    Disconnected,
    Connected,
    Connecting,
    RequiresCredentials
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
Changing to Connecting...
Changing to RequiresCredentials...
Enter username
ThisIsMyUserName
Enter password
ThisIsMyPassword
Connected.
```

This is a rather backwards use of Rx though: If you're looking to use Rx in an iterative, procedural way, why don't you just use C# and save yourself complexity?

Comment: Thanks @Shiomo ultimately this class will be used in an entirely async fashion when hosted as a 'real' app console is just for experimentation. It's in a PCL library which will be used by various Xamarin based hosts. The need for credentials will be a prompt if they change or expire so I thought that Rx would be a good fit for background prompts and also for starting and stopping other parts of my more complex background db sync'ing processes. The app is designed to work both on and offline so although my example is a little basic I was of the belief that Rx would be a good fit later on.